HX-Trigger to issue a request using arguments
I want to create a request after a trigger using htmx after a button was clicked with django:
def SomeView(request, var1, var2):
    trigger_data = json.dumps({"dlstart": {"pid": pid, "var1": var1}})
    return HttpResponse("", headers={"HX-Trigger": trigger_data})

I can see in the Network Tab the GET request is working. But now I want to add the two arguments from trigger_data to my hx-get dynamically. I did not find a way in htmx alone to achieve this, so I did a JS workaround (which I would gladly drop in favor of a htmx only solution):
document.body.addEventListener("dlstart", function() {
    const url = `/someURL/${event.detail.pid}/${event.detail.var1}`;
    const filename = "test.png";

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('was not ok');
            }
            return response.blob(); 
        })
        .then(blob => {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = filename; 
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click(); // feels so ugly
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        })
});

I imagine some combination of hx-get and dynamically add the arguments must work too?
Edit:
SomeView is just being called by a click on a button.
def DLView(request, pid, var1): 
    ## stuff        
    prod = Product.objects.get(id=pid)
    pdf = pdf_create(prod, var1)
    with open(pdf, "rb") as pdf_file:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf_file.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = f"""attachment; filename="{pdf}" """ # filename not used, see js part
        return response

urls:
    path("someurl/<int:pid>/<str:var1>", DLView, name="some-url"),

In the solution suggested I added a modal save button like this:
<button type="submit"
        id="start-dl-button"
        hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'
        hx-post="{% url 'start-dl' pid  var1 %}" 
        hx-on::before-request="document.getElementById('modal-container-{{ pid }}').innerHTML=''">
    Start DL
</button>


If you're already supplying the arguments from SomeView, you can create the url from there and supply it as context.

I might just think too complicated. Can you reply with a code? Do you mean answering with an oob-swap that has hx-trigger="load" and a hx-get  on the download with hx-target="None" or something similar?

Can you show which view is calling SomeView and your urlpatterns. I can show an example code.

I added some code representing the view.

I answered, check if that works.

It is pretty sneaky to download a server-generated file with htmx-powered requests. But there is an easy workaround that avoids any custom JavaScript at all.
The general idea is to have a view that only offers the download option to the client, like you're doing. The trick then is to simply redirect the request to that view.
In your case, first refactor SomeView:
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def SomeView(request, var1, var2):
    dl_url = reverse_lazy("some-url", kwargs=dict(pid=pid, var1=var1))
    return HttpResponse(headers={"Hx-Redirect" : dl_url})


This will issue a client redirect to the supplied url. Then in the DLView, return a FileResponse that makes is easy to offer a download option to the client:
from django.http import FileResponse

def DLView(request, pid, var1): 
    # do stuff
    pdf = pdf_create(prod, var1)
    return FileResponse(open(pdf, "rb"), as_attachment=True, filename="test.pdf")

This view should do what your JavaScript is doing by opening a download dialog in the browser. I hope that's what you wish to accomplish.
Note:
It's a convention that function names in Python should be in snake_case, while class names should be in PascalCase. Thus, instead of def DLView..., it should be def dl_view....
EDIT
To close the modal before the download starts you can listen to afterRequest event on the button, and add any modal-closing logic there:
<button hx-on::after-request="document.getElementById('modal-id').classList.remove('is-active')" ...>Print </button>

I am not familiar with Bulma so include whatever logic you're using to close the modal.

I would need some part on the template too, because the button not only starts a download but also closed a modal window. Can I handle this with your solution? Can HTMX react on the hx-redirect in the template?

Is your modal a native HTML dialog element or from a library like bootstrap?

bulma.io not bootstrap, to be exact :)
<button class="button" type="submit" id="start-dl-button" hx-headers='{"X-CSRF..."}' hx-post="{% url 'dl-view' pid var1 %}" hx-target="#the-modal-container-{{ pid }}">Print </button>

Check the edited answer.

works like a charm. Any idea how I could avoid the hx-on::after-request="" js code and implement a pure htmx solution? Thank you!!

I added how I implemented your code to do what I wanted to accomplish: Trigger a modal close and start a download at the same time. I wish I could do it without JS though.

I'm afraid you can't avoid inline JavaScript in this case. Manually closing modal dialogs almost always requires some JavaScript, and there is no 'htmx' way of doing it. The only approach I know is what I shared.

BTW, the hx-on... attribute is the htmx-way of hooking into the JavaScript API, so technically, it is still pure htmx as it avoids defining the logic in the script tag. Perhaps you have a particular problem with it?

I usually just use a hx-get that switches out the modal dialog with "". I thought it could maybe somehow be combined and there is a straight forward way to do it (surely I am not the first one to think about that).
